# Read location in DOM (webpage) and change navmenu classes accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, nav

I have a nav menu that links to certain parts of the page. I want to write some JS so that a class is added to each nav menu item when the scroll bar passes their respective part of the HTML. I believe I already know how to add classes to my navmenu items, so is there a specific way in JS to identify where in the DOM the user is?

To change the classes in the navbar dynamically, I use something like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var menu_items_links = $(".menu li a");
        menu_items_links.each(function () {
            if ($(this).is('[href*="#CURRENT LOCATION IN DOM"]')) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('current-location');
            }
        })
    });
```

Where the class will add the highlight/underline to the navmenu item to show that the user is at the specific location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what finally worked for me was using [WaypointJS](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/). I basically just set waypoints at the specific parts of the DOM and then I could define what I want to happen at those places. Here's the code in the end:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var menu_items_links = $(".menu li a");
    menu_items_links.each(function () {
        if ($(this).is('[href*="#"]')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('current-menu-item current-menu-ancestor');
        }
    })
    
    new Waypoint({
      element: document.getElementById('explore'),
      direction: 'down',
      handler: function() {
        console.log("FIRST WAYPOINT IS ACTIVE.");
        document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#explore']").parentElement.classList.add('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
        document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#build']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
        document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#connect']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
      },
      offset: '25%',
      continuous: false
  });  

  new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('explore'),
    direction: 'up',
    handler: function() {
      console.log("DEACTIVATING WAYPOINT.");
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#explore']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
    },
    offset: '35%',
});  

  new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('build'),
    handler: function() {
      console.log("SECOND WAYPOINT IS ACTIVE.");
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#build']").parentElement.classList.add('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#explore']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#connect']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
    },
    offset: '50%',
    continuous: false
}); 

new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('connect'),
    handler: function() {
      console.log("THIRD WAYPOINT IS ACTIVE.");
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#connect']").parentElement.classList.add('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#build']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
      document.querySelector("a[href='/manitoba/#explore']").parentElement.classList.remove('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor');
    },
    offset: '50%',
    continuous: false
    });  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use any `scroll spy` plugin for this or use the below implementation

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elems = $('.scrollspy');
    elems.each(function(index){
      var elemTop   = $(this).offset().top;
      var elemBottom    = elemTop + $(this).height();
      if(currentTop >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom){ //Current location tracking
        var id      = $(this).attr('id');
        var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id+ '"]');
    navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
      }
    })
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

#nav{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:50%;
}

section{
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-template">
        <div class="row col-xs-12 text-center">
          <ul>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#AboutUs">AboutUs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Images">Images</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="Home">
      Home
      </section>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="AboutUs">
      AboutUs
      </section>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="Images">
      Images
      </section>

      <section class="scrollspy" id="Contact">
      Contact
      </section>
</body>
```

Take a look at this scroll spy plugin https://github.com/r3plica/Scrollspy

Comment: I looked into using `scroll spy` as we have bootstrap installed on the site, but the menu is unfortunately set up as a `header` and not as a `nav`. 

At first I thought your method wouldn't apply but after reading it with a clear head, I think that it still might.. I'll give it another go and get back to you.